# grep - List all lines not containing both pattern

Tags: bash, grep

I have a text file having some records. I have two patterns to verify and I want to list all lines from the file not containing both pattern. How can I do this using `grep` command?
I tried few things using `grep -v` but nothing seem to work.

Suppose my text file is as follows.
1. qwer`pattern1`yui
2. ads`pattern2`asd
3. cczxczc
4. jkjk`pattern2`adsda`pattern1`

I want to list lines 1, 2 and 3 only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share what you have tried, along with sample input and expected output.

Comment: Why do you need to use grep? awk would be much simpler.

Comment: Since you did not explain this very well, you get a mess of an answer.  This `I have two patterns to verify and I want to list all lines from the file not containing either or both pattern. ` means that if there are any for of pattern, do not print the line, so in your example it would be only print line `3`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
grep -w -v -e "word1" -e "word2" file
```

OR else using `egrep`:

```
egrep -w -v -e "word1|word2" file
```

**UPDATE:** Based on comments, it seems following awk will work better:

```
awk '!(/pattern1/ && /pattern2/)' file
```

Comment: Thie will list the line even though both words are present

Comment: I want to list all lines excluding the ones which contain both words.

Comment: `!($0 ~ /word1/ && $0 ~ /word2/)` -> `!(/word1/ && /word2/)`. In this case `/word1/ && /word2/{next} 1` MIGHT be clearer but YMMV.

Comment: Oh thanks so much @EdMorton: I just realized and edited the same in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you like to try `awk`

```
awk '!/pattern1|pattern2/' file
```

It will not print any lines if it contains any of the patters

You can also expand this:

```
awk '!/pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4/' file
```

---

Example

```
cat file
one
two
three
four
one two
two
nine
six two
```

remove all lines with `one` or `two` or both of them.

```
awk '!/one|two/' file
three
four
nine
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. It is listing only when both patterns are not present.

Comment: This works fine, it may be you are using and old/defect `awk`

Comment: @Newbie Try changing "patter1" to "pattern1". This is the right solution. +1

Comment: @EdMorton: `'!/pattern1|pattern2/'` isn't same as `'!($0 ~ /pattern1/ && $0 ~ /pattern2/)'`

Comment: No, it's not. I see now that the OP only wanted to exclude lines containing both REs, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm keeping up with the comments and edits right, I think this is what you need:

```
$ grep -E -v 'pattern1.*pattern2|pattern2.*pattern1' test
1. qwerpattern1yui
2. adspattern2asd
3. cczxczc
$
```

Answer (score 0):

While the standard tools-based answers (`awk`, `grep`, etc) are generally simpler and more straightforward, for completion if you needed a pure-bash solution, you could do this:

```
$ while IFS= read -r ln; do [[ $ln =~ pattern1 ]] && [[ $ln =~ pattern2 ]] && continue; printf "%s\n" "$ln"; done < test 
1. qwerpattern1yui
2. adspattern2asd
3. cczxczc
$
```

Comment: Try that with an input line of `this is 100% the wrong approach`.

Comment: Thanks. Any insights on why someone would want to do that instead of the trivial alternative of `awk '!(/pattern1/ && /pattern2/)' file`? I always wonder about that when I see these relatively long, complex shell solutions and I wonder if the OP reading it thinks that there must be some benefit and what they think that would be...